# Increasing the height of root panel in gwt

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap, gwt-bootstrap

I have a html panel and i want to add the html panel to browser screen hence i used `rootPanel.get().add(htmlPanel);`. But their is a extra space between the starting of the screen and the first widget in html panel (As in image). I tried with setting `rootPanel.get().setheight("100%") and rootPanel.get().setsize("100%","100%")` but it doesn't seem to work please help i want to remove the extra space and so that the widget starts from beginning.

[image]

Comment: Did you inspect that "extra space" with your browser's Dev Tools? You're adding the `htmlPanel` at the _end_ of the `RootPanel.get()` (i.e. the `<body>` element), so have a look what you already have in there.

Comment: yes its automatically adding a padding of 50px can u please tell me how can i remove it

Comment: Which element the padding is added to? what's the selector that adds it? and which stylesheet does it come from? The Dev Tools should give you all the needed information to debug that issue.

Comment: Its adding padding to the body element in gwt-bootstrap css and every time when i war is generated this is re-created hence im not able to change the css property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This padding is added by GWT Bootstrap for its `NavBar` widget. See the note in the [javadoc](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/gwt-bootstrap/apidocs/com/github/gwtbootstrap/client/ui/Navbar.html):

> **NOTE:** We assume that most people will use the `ResponsiveNavbar`, so, we automatically add a `padding-top: 50px` in `body`.If you don't want this, you have to put a `padding-top: 0px;` manually in your document `body` tag.

See also https://github.com/gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap/issues/120

Comment: At this point, it seems like gwt-bootstrap is a pile of crap, and you'd better use Bootstrap without gwt-bootstrap.